# opportunities : how to check if the amount was filled

Tags: opportunity, validation

I have seen this multiple times that Sales users only care to fill in the monetary value of an opportunity once the opportunity becomes more concrete.

We can tell them that it's a better practice to already estimate what the opportunity will be worth but if they don't do it, there's nothing much you can do really.

Now, in a recent request, I needed to implement something so that the monetary value of an opportunity (the amount) needs to be know as from a certain stage and up. ("Negotiation" stage in this case)

I used a validation rule for this which worked well.

Now, I got a remark that for some products, it should also be possible to have a 0 monetary value...

So the question is, **is it possible to know the difference between an opportunity where no amount was specified or if the amount that was specified was just 0?**

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.  Use the ISBLANK function in the error condition formula in a validation rule:

```
ISBLANK(Amount)
```

That will evaluate to true if nothing was entered and false if 0 was entered.

Comment: And what if the amount is getting updated by the opportunity lines that are added? Or should I then just put the validation rules on opportunity product?

Comment: Are you able to set the Sales Price to blank for an Opportunity Product?  I thought it was always required.

Comment: that will be my issue then. They are adding their products to the opportunities but don't specify the price from the beginning. Because of that, the default 0 price is set and this updates the amount of the opportunity also to 0. So unfortunatly, the value of a product can't be blank so I don't immediatly see a way of checking if users entered a price or not for the products in their opportunities.

Answer (score 1):

Since sales price on opportunity product is required and can't be blank, based on the sales price field itself, there's no way of knowing if the user has set 0 as the price (for products offered for free) or if the user just didn't fill in any price.

To make this distinction, I'm thinking of using a "for free" checkbox on opportunity product level to make this distinction.

To check if the user has supplied a price for each product in the opportunity, I can create a roll-up summary field "products without a price" that checks on all products with price 0 that are not marked as for free.

My validationrule on the opportunity then can use that rollup field to see if all products have a price.

If there are other suggestions, more then welcome!

Comment: I was just thinking the same exact thing and was about to respond back to you in my comment. :)

Comment: great minds think alike :) thanks for thinking with me